# Old sci-fi short story about buying an android?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, androids

Long, long time ago I came upon a collection of old (pre 1980s?) short sci-fi stories. I'm not 100% sure, but something makes me think they were by Russian authors.

One of them was about a woman, who lives a lonely life in her flat. She decides to buy a male android. There's an android factory where you can choose your android's characteristic. First she chooses the 'basic' version, but is unhappy, because it lacks any specific character. She sends him to a factory so that they can improve his character. She's happy for some time, but soon she finds out he doesn't have his own opinion. She resends him to a factory and they improve him again. Again, she's happy for some time, but she finds out that the android doesn't have a free will and his feelings to her are programmed, not 'true'. Again, she sends him to the factory. They warn her that the android having a free will can do anything and might as well not return to her at all. She's determined to do that anyway. She sends him to the factory and waits in her flat for his return. At this point the story ends; we never find out whether the android came back to her.

I can't remember neither the title nor the author and I'm not able to google it. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Not Asimov's _[Satisfaction Guaranteed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_Guaranteed_%28short_story%29)_?

Comment: this may help you 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_robots_and_androids